# psftp - Script file is not running

Tags: file, shell, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a script as sftpScript.bat and trying to run it in psftp. here is what I am trying in psftp (I have tried through cmd and then entering psftp):

```
psftp>open L2_SERVSEND@ecdev1.idev.fedex.com 60022 -b sftpScript.bat
Using username "L2_SERVSEND"
Connected to hostSSH server: password
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Enter password for L2_SERVSEND
Password: 
Remote working directory is /L2_SERVSEND
psftp>
```

(I provided the password for the user when it asked!)

here is what my script file contains -

```
cd ..
cd L2_SERVRCV\APPTYPE
put sample.txt
put sample.txt
put sample.txt
put sample.txt
put sample.txt
put sample.txt
put sample.txt
```

Basically, I am tring to go inside the receiver's folder and then transfer sample.txt file to receiver i.e. L2_SERVRCV

I tried using -P while giving the port no but getting error "Port no invalid"; not sure why - that is not the priority as of now.

What I am expecting is that the script file should run and the sample.txt file should be transferred. But its not happening really!

P.S. - My all the files (psftp.exe, sftpScript.bat and the sample.txt) are in the same folder i.e. desktop.

Comment: Use a forward slash `/` instead of a backslash `\ `

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman! I am wondering how I did that silly mistake..well got to know one more thing that I don't need to run psftp.exe from cmd prompt. I can just go to my desktop in cmd and run the command "psftp L2_SERVSEND@ecdev1.idev.fedex.com -P 60022 -b sftpscript.bat". Thanks again.